# Объединить запросы к трем таблицам MySQL в один

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Есть 3 условия и в каждом условии запросы к разным таблицам.
Как мне объединить эти три запроса в один?

```
$sql_query = "SELECT user_id, user_search_pref, user_photo, user_birthday, user_country_city_name FROM `".PREFIX."_users` WHERE user_search_pref LIKE '%".$query."%' AND user_delet = '0' AND user_ban = '0' ORDER by `user_photo` DESC, `user_country_city_name` DESC LIMIT 0, ".$limit_sql;

$sql_query = "SELECT id, photo, title, add_date, owner_user_id FROM `".PREFIX."_videos` WHERE title LIKE '%".$query."%' AND privacy = 1 ORDER by `views` DESC LIMIT 0, ".$limit_sql;

$sql_query = "SELECT id, title, photo, traf, adres FROM `".PREFIX."_communities` WHERE title LIKE '%".$query."%' AND del = '0' AND ban = '0' ORDER by `traf` DESC, `photo` DESC LIMIT 0, ".$limit_sql;
```

**EDITED:**

Хочу вывести все совпадения по введенному слову в форму для поиска. Например: Я ввел слово вася и мне выдало 5 результатов

- 2 видео (**вася** гуляет, **вася** спит),
- 2 страницы пользователя (**вася** пупкин, **вася** мажоров), и
- 1 группа (**вася** снимает бред).

Comment: Зачем их объединять в один?

Comment: @Etki чтобы вывести результаты поиска по всем критериям.

Comment: @gm-111, вам надо определиться: вы хотите вывести ЧТО. от этого зависит техника объединения. В своем ответе я попробовал показать разные варианты. Вам надо конкретизировать вопрос.

Comment: @artoodetoo я хочу вывести все совпадения по введенному слову в форму для поиска. Например: Я ввел слово **вася** и мне выдало 5 результатов - 2 видео (**вася** гуляет, **вася** спит), 2 страницы пользователя (**вася** пупкин, **вася** мажоров), и 1 группа (**вася** снимает бред). Так понятно?

Comment: Внес за вас правки в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Из вопроса не очевидно что вы понимаете под "объединением".

Если все запросы возвращают совместимый набор колонок, вы можете применить "клей" UNION или UNION ALL:

```
SELECT id, alfa FROM xxx
  UNION ALL
SELECT id, beta FROM yyy
… и так далее
```

Результат будет состоять из полного набора строк всех под-запросов. В случае UNION (без all) этот набор дополнительно будет отфильтрован на уникальность записей. Подобную операцию чаще всего используют для склейки запросов *к одним и тем же* данным, но с разными условиями.

С другой стороны, люди в теме обычно называют "объединением" пересечение разнородных таблиц по определенному условию. Надо указать что в этих таблицах *общего*: смотри условие ON:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM 
  relations AS r INNER JOIN
  users AS u ON u.id = r.to_id
WHERE
  r.from_id = 10
```

Comment: я хочу вывести все совпадения по введенному слову в форму для поиска. Например: Я ввел слово **вася** и мне выдало 5 результатов - 2 видео (**вася** гуляет, **вася** спит), 2 страницы пользователя (**вася** пупкин, **вася** мажоров), и 1 группа (**вася** снимает бред). Алсо, в mysql ничего не понимаю, можно ли примеры делать на моих примерах?

Comment: Похоже ваш первый вариант. Просто сделайте одинаковый набор колонок в каждом подзапросе, а между ними напишите слова UNION ALL. Не просто, а очень просто.

Comment: @artoo.detoo разобрался, понятно, но как завершить эту выборку? У меня идет ORDER by xxx DESC LIMIT 0, ".$limit_sql как это приладить? И нужны ли кавычки на имена таблиц и колонок?

Comment: Текущий вопрос решен? Развивать и углублять тему можно бесконечно, но в обычаях S.O. задавать маленькие конкретные вопросы в отдельных темах. Так будет польза не только вам, но и тем, кто придет через поисковик.

Comment: **Текущий вопрос решен?** нет, вы дали не полный ответ.

Comment: Ну, желаю удачи! А я пасс.